# How to fetch dates from SQL by matching my travel dates?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How to fetch my travel dates with respect to `hotel_id`, `occu_type`, `season_start` & `season_end`?

**If my travel dates lies between two sessions for example my dates are 30/08/2015,31/08/2015,01/09/2015,02/09/2015 and 03/09/2015.**

I am using following query for this in PDO...

```
$sql = $this->dbObj->query(
  select DISTINCT season_start, season_end from nwts_hotel_room_rate 
  where hotel_id = '".$hotelid."' and occu_type = '".$arrayRmtypeopt."' and
    ('".$arrardepDate."' >= season_start and '".$arrardepDate."' < season_end)
  );
```

Database:-

http://www93.zippyshare.com/v/H33KasNa/file.html
http://www39.zippyshare.com/v/KO2qYYyu/file.html

Please share any solution...

Comment: I don't clearly understood your question. Why you need to get your travel date from the query while you already have these date?

Comment: if you are using pdo you should be using prepared statements

Comment: doesn't matter...prepare & query both gives same results...

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you're picking two date periods, right?

dateStart1
dateEnd1

and

dateStart2
dateEnd2

Query will be something like this:

...
and (season_start <= dateStart1 and dateEnd1 <= season_end)
and (season_start <= dateStart2 and season_end <= dateEnd2)

Comment: Glad to help). If it solved the problem, you can set this question to answered.